# use blog name and id in url using yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii-url-manager

I need to use blogname  and id on the url on Yii2 like this is my url now :-
http://localhost/html/demo/web/site/blog/blogdetail?id=39

I want to modify this link to :-

http://localhost/html/demo/web/site/blog/blogdetail/39/Did-Facebook-Skew-The-2016

This is my blog name "Did-Facebook-Skew-The-2016"

for this i am using that code:-
web.php file.

```
   'rules' => array(
                     'blog/blogdetail/<id:\w+>/<name:\w+>'=>'site/blog/blogdetail/id/<id>/name/<name>/',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
```

and in view this is my link:-

```
 <a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl([$blogid.'/'.$model->title]); ?>">
```

Comment: Good tutorial for you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-sluggable-behavior--cms-23222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['site/blog/blogdetail', 'id'=>$blogid, 'name'=>$model->title]); ?>">
```

As a sidenote, you can change the route from

```
'blog/blogdetail/<id:\w+>/<name:\w+>'=>'site/blog/blogdetail/id/<id>/name/<name>/',
```

to

`'blog/blogdetail/<id:\w+>/<name:\w+>'=>'site/blog/blogdetail/',`

Named params (id and name in this case) are automatically passed to the action.

EDIT:
If you have problem with the params type you can change

```
<name:\w+>
```

with

```
<name:[\w-]+>
```

Your slug (Did-Facebook-Skew-The-2016) should now match.

Comment: Your route is kinda strange, 'site' is a module?

Comment: your code working fine, when my blog name is one letter (eg. testblog) but if my name is of two or more then two  words like (eg. test blog name) its not working

Comment: Check edit. You can also change the ID type from \w to \d